# auto upload videos to youtube from ftp server

Tags: wordpress, youtube

i have whm cpanel server and videos stored from a folder "abc", uploaded through filezilla.

Is there anyway to upload them to youtube automatically?

prefer php solutions which can be integrated with wordpress

Thanks

Comment: Not automatically by FTPing. But you can use the API in the answer below to create a PHP extension that will scan your upload directory for new videos and send them to YouTube when you visit a page. Or if you have access to cron, create a php script that is run every few minutes to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

you should go through youtube developers api, php guide its well documented to serve your answer 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php